# Plot a ROC curve in R without using any packages

Tags: r, roc

Hi i am pretty new to programming in R and i am having troble plotting a ROC curve without using any package.

I generated my data using:

```
d=rpearsonIII(100,0.5,360,20)
nd=rnorm(100,450,25)
```

i need a vector with values <400 for d and >400 for nd, so i did:

```
spec = (cumsum(nd[nd>400])/sum(nd))*100
sens = (cumsum(d[d<400])/sum(nd))*100
```

and the i plotted like this:

```
plot(1-spec,sens)
```

but the plot was nothing like i expected it to be

Edit:
Thanks to the advice given my code looks like this now:

```
sc2 = c(rnorm(50,450,25),rpearsonIII(50,0.5,360,20))
scF = sc2 < 395

thresholds <- sort(sc2)

pos <- sum(scF);pos
neg <- sum(!scF);neg

tn <- cumsum(!scF);tn
spec <- tn/neg;spec

tp <- pos - cumsum(scF);tp
sens <- tp/pos;sens

plot(1 - spec, sens, type = "l", col = "red", 
     ylab = "Sensitivity", xlab = "1 - Specificity")
abline(c(0,0),c(1,1))
```

The plotted roc curve looks like this:
[roc curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUuH7.png)

My problem now is that if change the order of the generated data (rnorm and rpearsonIII), the curve is reversed.

Comment: Your lengths for spec and sens are different. They have to be equal to use plot() like you are.

Comment: What are the scores for your data?  To make and ROC curve, you need actual classes (which seems to be your `scF` value) as well as a score you gave each element to predict the class.

Comment: The scores for my data is my `sc2` value. Maybe i am misunderstanding what are the scores...

Comment: You may want to visit [this page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126048/) for more of an explanation, but for an ROC curve, you need two things, the "truth value" (`actuals`) and some kind numeric predictor you are using to predict the truth value (`score`), usually the output of a classifier. ROC is a visualization of how well the predictor corresponds with the truth. For example you might use height as a predictor for "is minor" (age >= 18). In your code, since `scF` is derived directly from `sc2`, it would be like using age to predict "is minor". Your ROC will be perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice @Barker! 
One last question, could you give a suggestion on how to calculate the area under the curve (AUC), after obtaining the ROC curve using the method you described here?

Comment: Added AUC to the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what `rpearsonIII` is, so I am just going to make a sample random data with actual classes `actuals` as well as the scores for the predictions `scores`.

```
set.seed(100)
actuals <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 100, replace = TRUE)
scores <- runif(100,-1,1)
```

### The long version with explanation

If in your data the actuals are strings or factors rather than logicals, you will need to convert them to logicals using:

```
actuals <- actuals == "postiveClass"
```

Next we want to order the instances based on their scores.  We can do this using:

```
actuals <- actuals[order(scores)]
```

If you want to keep track of the thresholds for the sensitivities and specificity, you can keep them aligned using:

```
thresholds <- sort(scores)
```

Now we need to get our sensitivities and specificities.  Sensitivity is `TP/P` and specificity is `TN/N`.  Getting the total number of positives `P` is easy, since our actuals are logical, we can just use `sum(actuals)`.  Similarity, we can get our negatives `N` using `sum(!actuals)`.

```
pos <- sum(actuals)
neg <- sum(!actuals)
```

First lets get our true negatives at each threshold.  That is pretty easy, it is just the number of `FALSE` values at or below each the threshold.  Since our data are in order by threshold, we can calculate that (and the specificity) using:

```
tn <- cumsum(!actuals)
spec <- tn/neg
```

The number of true positives is slightly harder because we are looking for the number of positives *greater* that the threshold, so `cumsum` alone won't work.  However, since the number above the threshold is equal to the total minus number below or at the threshold, we can get our true positives using:

```
tp <- pos - cumsum(actuals)
sens <- tp/pos
```

Now all we need to do is plot the two.

```
plot(1 - spec, sens, type = "l", col = "red", 
     ylab = "Sensitivity", xlab = "1 - Specificity")
abline(c(0,0),c(1,1))
```

[image: ROC Plot]

To get the AUC of the curve, we simply need to calculate the height of the curve (the sensitivity) multiplied by the width the (difference in 1 - specificity) at each value of actuals.  We already have the sensitivity, we just need the specificity.  The `diff` function will give us our difference in adjacent values of specificity, however, we need to put a `0` value at the beginning to get the width of the first columns.

```
width <- diff(c(0, 1 - sens))
auc <- sum(spec*width)
```

### the minimal code version

```
actuals <- actuals[order(scores)]

sens <- (sum(actuals) - cumsum(actuals))/sum(actuals)
spec <- cumsum(!actuals)/sum(!actuals)

plot(1 - spec, sens, type = "l", col = "red", 
     ylab = "Sensitivity", xlab = "1 - Specificity")
abline(c(0,0),c(1,1))

(auc <- sum(spec*diff(c(0, 1 - sens))))
```

Comment: I used the package PearsonDS to get the rpearsonIII because i need to generate data that has a gamma distribution with the location parameter. So the variable "d" that i used has data with gamma distribution and "nd" has normal distribution. My goal is to plot a roc curve using data generated with those distributions